# Fuzzy Matching a list of names in Java

Tags: java, fuzzy-logic

I am trying to use fuzzy-matcher library to match a list of names from our data base.
The data is serialized into a java object, wanted to find out how we can map the data into the Document object defined in fuzzy-matcher library

https://github.com/intuit/fuzzy-matcher

Our User.java class has these attributes

- userId
- firstName
- lastName
- address
- etc ....

We have over 1000 users in our db, and would like to run these through fuzzy-matcher to help detect duplicates.

Any code snippet that can help us better understand the library would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the `User` object maps to `Document` whereas each attributes will need to map to an `Element` object in fuzzy-matcher

If you have a Collection of the `User` object in java, you can convert it to Document/Element objects like this

```
List<User> users = // fetch data from db

List<Document> documents = users.stream().map(user -> {
return new Document.Builder(userId)
            .addElement(new Element.Builder<String>().setValue(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName()).setType(NAME).createElement())
            .addElement(new Element.Builder<String>().setValue(user.getAddress()).setType(ADDRESS).createElement())
            .createDocument();
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Once you have a List of Documents, you can pass it to one of the methods in MatchService to trigger a fuzzy match

```
MatchService matchService = new MatchService();
Map<String, List<Match<Document>>> result = matchService.applyMatchByDocId(documents);
```

Note that this above method will return you a result which is grouped by the userId